# Ответ на input()

Tags: python, input

Можно ли на python3 как-то ответить на `input()` программой, а не вводом пользователя? Я думаю что нет, но вдруг... мне нужно

P.S.не удаляйте, пжлст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам нужно ответить на input() из программы другой программой то можно использовать keyboard.

```
pip install keyboard
```

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write('Ответ на input.')
```

Comment: спасибо, но у меня почему-то работает через раз. Иногда отвечает на `input`, иногда нет(

Answer (score 1):

Можно через перенаправление потока ввода через командную строку. Скрипт:

```
answer = input("Who is on duty today?")
print()
print("Your answer:", answer)
```

Запускаем (на Windows используйте python вместо python3):

```bash
❯ echo Not me! | python3 test.py
Who is on duty today?
Your answer: Not me!
```

Здесь оператор `|` перенаправляет вывод команды слева от него как ввод для команды справа. Вместо `echo` может быть запуск другого python-скрипта, который, например, что-то выводит через `print` и это будет передаваться на вход во второй скрипт.